# Oaxaca Decomposition: Unexplained Constant

Tags: multiple-regression, stata, matrix-decomposition

I am doing an Oaxaca decomposition of the Log Wage Differential between Whites and non-Whites. I would like to find out if there is any interpretation for the constant term under the unexplained component? Can I attribute it to general unobserved group differences in unobserved characteristics?

```
unexplained |
  lnwage |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
   _cons |   .6121434   .0967975     6.32   0.000     .4224239     .801863
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume the "twofold" decomposition model where the mean outcome difference is accounted for by **i)** group differences in the predictor variables; and **ii)** an unexplained component.

Additionally, you are interested in the detailed contributions of each predictor variable to both **i)** and **ii)**. That is, you want to know how much group differences for each $X_i$ contribute to the explained component and how much differing returns to $X_i$ (i.e. coefficients) is related with the unexplained component. (You don't show complete results, nor Stata code, but this seems to be your case.)

Now take a simple model with one predictor:

$Y_l = \beta_{0l} + \beta_{1l} X_l + \epsilon_l$

where $l \in \{A,B\}$ and $A, B$ denote two different groups.

Under some assumptions, the unexplained component **(ii)** of this model, can be written as

$\hat{U} = (\hat{\beta}_{0A} - \hat{\beta}_{0B}) + (\hat{\beta}_{1A} - \hat{\beta}_{1B}) \bar{X}_B$

where $\hat{\beta}$s denote estimated coefficients and $\bar{X}$ the mean of $X$.

Your question involves the difference in the intercept terms of both groups and its relation to the unexplained component. That corresponds precisely to the first term in the right-hand-side of the last equation, and is interpreted as the contribution of "group membership" to the unexplained gap of the outcome variable between groups $A$ and $B$. The second term is the contribution of differing returns to $X$.

Succinctly: of the unexplained component, there is one part due to the difference between the intercept of the equations for those in group $A$ and $B$. This is the difference in $Y$ due to "group membership" alone; that is, by virtue of agents belonging to two different groups, and nothing else.

**References:**

Jann, Ben (2008). The Blinder–Oaxaca decomposition for linear regression models. The Stata Journal 8, number 4.

Jones, F. L., and J. Kelley (1984). Decomposing differences between groups: A cautionary note on measuring discrimination. Sociological Methods and Research 12.

(Both are freely available with a web search.)

Comment: thanks so much for the reply :)! Greatly appreciate your help!